# Postgresql. Использование переменных в транзакции

Tags: sql, postgresql, transaction

Нужна транзакция, которая в различные таблицы записывала данные, создавая или редактируя уже существующие записи.

Сама транзакция генерится на бэкенде. Часть значений для записей таблиц вставляется, остальная часть данных (идентификаторы связанных сущностей), добавляются в процессе выполнения транзакции, через переменные.

Собственно написал такую:

```
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO good (article, category_id, name, active, date_create, date_modify) 
        VALUES (1751692, 5089, 'Смартфон Lenovo A2010 Red LTE PA1J0142RU__1', true, 
            '2022-02-04 18:51:17', '2022-02-04 18:51:17')
        ON CONFLICT (article)
        DO UPDATE SET article=1751692, category_id=5089, name='Смартфон Lenovo A2010 Red 
        LTE PA1J0142RU__1', active=true RETURNING id;
        good := lastval();

        INSERT INTO property (good_id, property_key_id) VALUES (:good, 1775)
        ON CONFLICT (good_id, property_key_id)
        DO UPDATE SET good_id=:good, property_key_id=1775 RETURNING id
        property := lastval();

        DELETE FROM property_text_value WHERE property_id=:property;

        INSERT INTO property_text_value (property_id, value) VALUES (:property, '1000');

        INSERT INTO property (good_id, property_key_id) VALUES (:good, 3)
        ON CONFLICT (good_id, property_key_id)
        DO UPDATE SET good_id=:good, property_key_id=3 RETURNING id
        property := lastval();

        DELETE FROM property_text_value WHERE property_id=:property;

        INSERT INTO property_text_value (property_id, value) VALUES (:property, 
            '8899557720081');
    
        SELECT article FROM good WHERE id = :good;
    COMMIT;
```

Проблема возникает при установке переменных (good, property) и получении из них данных для запроса (...= :good, ... = : property).

```
    SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "good"
    LINE 4:         good := lastval();INSERT INTO property (good_id, pro...
                    ^
```

Переменные пробовал задавать и через конструкцию with good as (....) и  через declare good int и т.п. В каждом варианте возникают свои проблемы.

С postgres только начал работать, подобную транзакцию писал ранее на martiaDB, там все отлично отрабатывало. Собственно сейчас переписываю под postgres.

Как прокидывать идентификаторы в переменные и использовать эти переменные в дальнейших запросах.
Причем ни функция ни процедура не нужна, именно в условиях транзакции.

Заранее спасибо...

Comment: вам надо обернуть весь ваш being ... end в процедуру и вызывать уже процедуру

Comment: в том то и дело, что мне не подходит ни процедура ни функция, а именно транзакционный запрос, т.к. характеристик может быть от 0 и более, т.е. запрос каждый запрос будет уникальный, но в нем есть динамические значения - good_id и property_id. Как мне передавать в эти переменные значения и использовать в запросах?